# TableAdapterManager and Related tables in MS Access

Tags: c#, tableadapter, ms-access-2010

I am writing my first database application in c# and I have to use MS Access database, I have two tables Invoice and Order the order table is a child table. Invoice is a parent table it has key column "InvoiceNumber" which is auto column and it has a one to many relation with Order table column "InvoiceNumber". The problem I am having is that I got an exception at the line

```
tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(database1DataSet);
```

when I try to add a new row and click save,

```
"You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'Invoice'."
```

I tried to search but I am unable to find it any help for ms access database, most of them are of SQL database. I also found one solution to edit the relation in the dataset designer to select the option "Both relation and foreign key constraints" but it didnot work for me either.

Thanks

Comment: looks like you add row that doesn't have filled value of the foreign key column. Add code, that adds new row to table

Comment: @zabulus, since the relation is parent child then when I click the save button the tableAdapterManager updates the parent table so it got that row then it send update to the child row, so the record must be present. What I thought to use the tableAdapter.update() separately of parent first then of child but it didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your OleDbParameters are properly set and in the correct corresponding order as the columns in the tables in the database. If you use Visual Studio automated code generation for data sources when you add a database, then drag and drop a table onto a form, check out the `<database name>DataSet.Designer.cs` file. It will teach you all you need to know.